# Http Verb Attribute Not Working

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have decorated my service interface with Http Verb Attributes, but is not working.
Every method is treated as Post verb.

I'm using AspNetCore 1.1 and Abp packages 2.3.0

```
public interface ISettlementAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<PagedResultDto<SettlementListDto>> GetPaged(GetSettlementInput input);

    [HttpDelete]
    Task Cancel(EntityDto<string> input);
}
```

Comment: do you mean you decorated your actions in the controller with HttpGet, HttpPut or HttpDelete and all of them are still treated as HttpPost?, **Have you tried naming your actions as GetMethod, PutMethod, etc?**
Please put your code in your question

Comment: I'm not using controllers. I'm using the application services and dynamic webapi. According to this document [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API) it should works only by decorating the interface methods.
But i figure out that only works when the concrete class methods are decorated. Maybe this should be bug, i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this;

```
public class SettlementAppService : ISettlementAppService 
{

    [HttpDelete]
    Task Cancel(EntityDto<string> input){
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For AspNet Core, add these attributes to the application service class, not to interface. Because they are handled by AspNet Core MVC (not by ABP) and it does not know about interfaces.

From the documentation (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#controllers):

> Note: Previously, dynamic web api system was requiring to create service interfaces for application services. But this is not required for ASP.NET Core integration. Also, MVC attributes should be added to the service classes, even you have interfaces.